# rails 3.1: Where to filter out email addresses that have opted out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Trying to figure out the cleanest way prevent sending email to users who have opted out from receiving them in rails 3.1.

I was thinking about overriding Mail.deliver to check the db and determine if the recipients are unsubscribed or not, then conditionally delivering the email.

That seems like the least intrusive way to go about it, but requires creating the Mail objects that are never going to be sent.

Seems like the most resource conscious way would be to do the check in the controller, thus preventing the Mail objects that are never going to be sent from the burden of existence.

This though seems more intrusive and prone to developers forgetting to make the check when creating new mailers.

Is there a standard practice for this situation?

** edit **
This is for managing a collection of users who have opted out of receiving notifications, rather than something like managing subscriptions to a news letter.

Comment: How are you deciding who to email in the first place?  If you were keeping track of subscriptions, this is a no brainer (delete the subscription).

Comment: @numbers1311407 It's not a newsletter type thing but instead each user gets notification emails about various events in the system. They would be opting out of receiving those notification emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the attribute that determines whether or not to get email notifications is just a field on a model in the DB, you could create a named scope called something like 'want_email_notifications' to get all the users that *have* subscribed.

So, if you have a `User` class, and that class has an attribute called `opt_out`, then you could do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  named_scope :want_email_notifications, :conditions => ['opt_out = ?', false]

  ...
end
```

Then, to call it, you do `User.want_email_notifications`, which gives you an array of all `User` objects that want email notifications.

Then, when you're checking whether or not a given user should receive an email notification, write a condition similar to:

```
send_email_notification(user_in_question) if User.want_email_notifications.include?(user_in_question)
```

In this example, `send_email_notification` is the method where you would call the associated delivery method, which actually sends the email.

Comment: My situation involves already having a list of users that are going to get in app notifications, and then not sending notification emails to those that have opted out. The emails are sent automatically post_create of the notification. I ended up putting the filter in the post_create hook which is good enough for now. But I really appreciate the answer, and scopes are super usefull! Thanks and an upvote for you!